# The Value For The Column "idauthdata" Is Not Supplied When Querying The Table "authdata"

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I'am trying to do an authorization in my Yii application.
In my database I have the authData table which contains 2 primary key:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `authdata` (
  `idauthData` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `login` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  `role` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `employee_idEmployee` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idauthData`,`employee_idEmployee`),
  UNIQUE KEY `idauthData_UNIQUE` (`idauthData`),
  KEY `fk_authData_employee1_idx` (`employee_idEmployee`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

In my Authdata model I override the primaryKey() method:

```
 public function primaryKey() 
    {
            return array('idauthData', 'employee_idEmployee');
    }
```

But when I trying to find a row in Authdata activeRecord class using findByPk() method I`am getting an exception:

```
private function getModel(){
      if (!$this->isGuest && $this->_model === null){
          $this->_model = Authdata::model()->findByPk(array($this->id), array('select' => 'role'));
      }
      return $this->_model;
}
```

The exception has next description:
**The value for the column "idauthData" is not supplied when querying the table "authdata".**

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\helloworld\protected\components\WebUser.php(14): CActiveRecord->findByPk(array("15"), array("select" => "role"))
09 }
10 }
11 
12 private function getModel(){
13 if (!$this->isGuest && $this->_model === null){
14 $this->_model = Authdata::model()->findByPk(array($this->id), array('select' => 'role'));
15 }
16 return $this->_model;
17 }
18 }
19 ?>
```

And I don`t know how to resolve this problem.
I know that this is a simple mistake and I just miss some moment. That why if somebody could help me I will be very glad!
Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe add this column to `select` array?

Comment: excuse me, where should I do this?

Comment: `$this->_model = Authdata::model()->findByPk(array($this->id), array('select' => array('role', 'idauthData')));` Oh, and select value should be array

Comment: I did like you said, but the error is still shown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, now i know. You defined composite primary key, but you did not pass it to `findByPk`:

This should work:

```
Authdata::model()->findByPk(array(
    'idauthData' => $this->id,
    'employee_idEmployee' => $employeeId
), array('select' => 'role'));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot you was right. I didn`t pass the employee_idEmployee primary key to my findByPK() method.